# nginx multiple locations and roots inside

Tags: nginx, containers

i've an nginx container used as front-end for a web application.

This is my config file:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/log/host.access.log  main;

    root   /usr/share/nginx/html/shaka-player-master/demo;
    index  index.html index.htm;


    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    root           html;
    #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
    #    include        fastcgi_params;
    #}


    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}
}
```

If i point to localhost:port it returns me correctly /usr/share/nginx/html/shaka-player-master/demo/index.html ... but i have a problem:

This application, a dash library, needs i run a python script that generate files names "deps.js", base.js and others, hosted in:

```
/usr/share/nginx/html/shaka-player-master/third_party/closure/goog/base.js 
/usr/share/nginx/html/shaka-player-master/dist/deps.js 
/usr/share/nginx/html/shaka-player-master/shaka-player.uncompiled.js
```

These files are inside these folders, but browser returns me 404 because of i don't know how to expose these contents from config file.

I tried adding some code like:

```
location = third_party/closure/goog/base.js {

root /usr/share/nginx/html/shaka-player-master/third_party/closure/goog/base.js;
}
```

But still 404.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: These three files - what are their URIs? We need that information to construct the `location` and `root` directives. Which effectively maps URIs to pathnames.

Comment: For these 3 resources, browser does the following requests:   GET http://localhost:9900/third_party/closure/goog/base.js 

 GET http://localhost:9900/dist/deps.js 
GET http://localhost:9900/shaka-player.uncompiled.js

Comment: Maybe you should edit your question and add the information - the comment did not display it

Answer (score 1):

The correct `location` and `root` syntax would be:

```
location = /third_party/closure/goog/base.js {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/shaka-player-master;
}
location = /dist/deps.js {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/shaka-player-master;
}
location = /shaka-player.uncompiled.js {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/shaka-player-master;
}
```

See [location](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) and [root](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) manual pages for details.

There will also be configurations that allow this root to be the default and make the demo location the exception.

<del>However, there is another potential problem - why is your application using `localhost:9900` as the server name?</del>

Comment: Thanks for the solution, now it works. localhost:9900 because of this nginx container is on container's port 80 and is publish on host'port 9900.

Comment: i've added a related issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41741603/nginx-as-load-balancer-upstream-with-path