# nginx as load balancer: upstream with path

Tags: caching, nginx, docker, containers

i've an nginx container, on port 9200, that acts as load balancer. This is config file:

```
proxy_ignore_headers Set-Cookie;
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Range';


upstream backend {
        server 192.168.99.103:9500 weight=3;
        server 192.168.99.104:9500;
        server 192.168.99.105:9500;
    }

server {

listen 80;
server_name 172.17.0.1;

location = /LynyrdSkynyrdFreebirdAudio.mp4 {

            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Range';

            if ($request_method = OPTIONS ) {
               add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, OPTIONS";
               add_header Content-Length 0;
               add_header Content-Type text/plain;
               return 200;
                }
            proxy_pass http://backend/;

            add_header X-Upstream  $upstream_addr;

        }

       location = /LynyrdSkynyrdFreebirdVideo.mp4 {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Range';

            if ($request_method = OPTIONS ) {
               add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, OPTIONS";
               add_header Content-Length 0;
               add_header Content-Type text/plain;
               return 200;
                }

            proxy_pass http://backend;

            add_header X-Upstream  $upstream_addr;
        }

   }
```

This container load balance requests in the following way: when arrives a request `localhost:9200/LynyrdSkynyrdFreebirdVideo.mp4` or `localhost:9200/LynyrdSkynyrdFreebirdAudio.mp4`, it balances requests across 3 servers. 
These 3 servers are 3 nginx containers that acts as cache.
This is config file of nginx caches:

```
proxy_cache_path /tmp/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=my_zone:10m inactive=60m;
proxy_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";
proxy_cache_methods GET HEAD POST;
proxy_cache_valid 200 206 100m;
proxy_ignore_headers Set-Cookie;
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Range';
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  172.17.0.1;

    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/log/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    root           html;
    #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
    #    include        fastcgi_params;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}

    location /demo/ {

    proxy_cache my_zone;
    add_header X-Proxy-Cache             $upstream_cache_status;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For     $remote_addr;

    proxy_set_header Host                $host;

    proxy_pass http://172.17.0.1:8700/shaka-player-master/demo/index1.html ;

    }

location   /media {

    proxy_cache my_zone;
    add_header X-Proxy-Cache             $upstream_cache_status;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For     $remote_addr;

    proxy_set_header Host                $host;

    proxy_pass http://172.17.0.1:8700/shaka-player-master/media/example-av.mpd ;

  }

location =  /example-av1.mpd {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';

    proxy_cache my_zone;
    add_header X-Proxy-Cache             $upstream_cache_status;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For     $remote_addr;

    proxy_set_header Host                $host;

    proxy_pass http://192.168.99.103:9600/shaka-player/media/example-av1.mpd;
  }



location =  /LynyrdSkynyrdFreebirdVideo.mp4 {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Range';


    proxy_cache my_zone;
    add_header X-Proxy-Cache             $upstream_cache_status;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For     $remote_addr;

    proxy_set_header Host                $host;

    proxy_pass http://192.168.99.103:9600/shaka-player/media/LynyrdSkynyrdFreebirdVideo.mp4 ;

  }

location =  /LynyrdSkynyrdFreebirdAudio.mp4 {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Range';


    proxy_cache my_zone;
    add_header X-Proxy-Cache             $upstream_cache_status;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For     $remote_addr;

    proxy_set_header Host                $host;

    proxy_pass http://192.168.99.103:9600/shaka-player/media/LynyrdSkynyrdFreebirdAudio.mp4;

  }

}
```

If i point to load balancer, i.e. `localhost:9200/LynyrdSkynyrdFreebirdVideo.mp4` or `localhost:9200/LynyrdSkynyrdFreebirdAudio.mp4`, there is `404` not found. I expect that, if i point to this URL, load balancer balances request to `192.168.99.103(or 104, or 105):9500/LynyrdSkynyrdFreebirdVideo.mp`4 or `192.168.99.103(or 104, or 105):9500/LynyrdSkynyrdFreebirdAudio.mp4`.
But in the `upstream` block i don't know if in `server` directive i can add a path.

In fact, this is, i think, the very problem: in fact, if i point to 192.168.99.103`(or`104`, or`105`)`:9500/LynyrdSkynyrdFreebirdAudio(or Video).mp4, i get the content correctly.

Can anyone helps me?

Answer (score 4):

Solved:

i have added path to `http://backend`, like:

```
  proxy_pass http://backend/LynyrdSkynyrdFreebirdVideo.mp4;
```